# Continuity of function with multiple variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus, continuity

I'm trying to find the continuity of
$$\frac{(1-x)(1-y)}{1-x^2-y^2}$$
at the point $(1,0)$ assuming $f(1,0)=\frac12$. I guess I have to use the method with epsilon and delta, but it's so complicated to me, I can't find a way to get there by manipulating the function.

Comment: Hint: look at what happens when we take x->1 and y->0, then y->0 and x->1. What would you expect to happen if it's continuous?

Comment: The function is not defined on the unit circle $x^2+y^2=1$ minus $(1,0)$. To discuss continuity at $(1,0)$, it should be defined on an open neighborhood of $(1,0)$.

Comment: Like User203940 suggests, on this kind of question there is rarely any need to consider $\epsilon$s and $\delta$s

Comment: Just to be clear, I want to find if the limit of the function exists or not, by approaching (1,0) from different ways. If I get two different results it doesn't exist, cool, it's not continuous. If (looks like) it exists though, I have to prove for ALL different ways, so I have to use epsilon and delta. Then I'll check if it's equal to 1/2 or not. By the way, I know the function is not defined at (1,0), but we create a single point at (1,0) equal to 1/2, for the purpose of the question. So, how do I find the limit to f(x)? That's my problem, I have no idea what to do.

Comment: If you make a fixed point f(1,0) =1/2 it's still not continuous. Let x->1 for y fixed, then f(x,y)->0 which is not 1/2. @Song also gives a good idea of why it fails.

Comment: When y=0, I get (1-x)/(1-x^2). Do I use Hospital to get rid of the 0/0 indetermination? Can I do that here, is it valid/or the actual way to do it?